# Reset Radio value after modal close jquery

Tags: jquery, reset

Reset radio button is working fine using below code.

```
  $(function () {
     $(document).on("hidden.bs.modal", "#myModal", function () {
       $(':radio').prop('checked',false);
     });
  );
```

but when i open modal again at that time it take previously checked value

```
function show_second_modal() {
  if ($("input").is(':checked')) {
    var radioVal = $('input[name=amount]:checked').val();
    alert(radioVal);
    var radioValNum = Number(radioVal);
    $('input[name="amount"]').val(radioVal);
  } else {
    alert("Please Select Amount");
    return false;
  }

  $("#show_amt").text(radioVal);
  //$('#amount').val(radioVal);
  $('#myModal').modal('hide');
  $('#myModal1').modal('show');
}
```

Comment: Please consider adding your HTML as well. A minimal working example would be good. If you want to get help from any member here. Thanks

Comment: please provide a snippet to check

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on("hidden.bs.modal", "#myModal", function () {
   $('input[name=amount]').attr('checked',false);
 });
```

have you tried this?

Comment: This is working fine (checked is reseting )
but when i am opening modal again it takes previously checked value

Comment: USE DEBUGGER; and use console in chrome debugger to check the issue, i can't find the issue without providing a working jsfiddle/preview